# What is the difference between process.stderr.on('data') and process.on('error')?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, stderr

I'm setting up error handling for a child process in my node application, and I'm wondering about these two options:

```
    childProcess.on('error', err => {
        // omitted
    });

    // do we need both this and the preceding handler?
    childProcess.stderr.on('data', data => {
        // omitted
    });
```

What's the difference? Are both needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [child process `error` event](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error) is fired when node has a problem starting, stopping or managing the child process.

[`stderr`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stderr) is one of the output channels for the child process once it's running. The `data` event can be fired many times in normal operation of a process and can often include important information about error conditions of the process. You would normally handle [`stdout`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdout) in a similar fashion to `stderr`.

The [`exit` events](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) `code` value can also be important for a child process. Often processes will exit with a non `0` return code to signal an issue occurred.